# SwiftUI: Rounded Rectangle Overlay Corners Cut Off

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to have a consistent-width broder with an overlay, and I keep getting the wrong result. My overlay looks like this:

[image]

With this code:

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Test")
    }
    HStack {
        Text("test2")
    }
}
.padding()
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.95)
.frame(minHeight: 50)
.overlay (
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .stroke(RandomColor(), lineWidth: 3)
)
```

As you can see the corners are thicker than all other parts of the overlay. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `lineWidth` makes it stretch beyond its bounds slightly. You can balance this with `inset(by:)` to keep it inside the original frame:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
 .inset(by: 3)
 .stroke(RandomColor(), lineWidth: 3)
```

*Note: you may only need to inset by 2 -- haven't done enough experimentation to see what the exact number is*

Comment: 1.5 would be correct since the stroke gets centered on the border. Using strokeBorder as mentioned in the other comment is simpler since it handles the insetting for you.

Answer (score 23):

The thing you are missing is the difference between **stroke** and [**strokeBorder**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/insettableshape/strokeborder(_:style:antialiased:)), if you changed your code to **strokeBorder**, it  help you.

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
    .strokeBorder(RandomColor(), lineWidth: 3)
```